# How to filter avro events in topic using TopicRecordNameStrategy while consuming Kafka events?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, avro, spring-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I am using `@KafkaListener` from Spring Boot to consume avro events from a topic. My subject strategy: `TopicRecordNameStrategy`

If there are multiple avro events like `EmployeeCreatedEvent`, `EmployeeDeletedEvent` etc, how can i consume only `EmployeeDeletedEvent`?

Both of them have separate schema(.avsc)
Sample code:

```
public void myListener(ConsumerRecord<MyKey, EmployeeDeletedEvent> event, Acknowledgment ack) {
....
}
```

The above code receives EmployeeCreatedEvent as well.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How are you checking the messages are of type `EmployeeCreatedEvent` ? Or are you saying you get some type of ClassCastException here?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, yes i am getting ClassCastException. Even I have created 2 ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory : one for EmployeeCreatedEvent & another for EmployeeDeletedEvent . I took. help from the link https://howtodoinjava.com/kafka/multiple-consumers-example/ and changed as per my needs like using AvroDeSerializer etc.

Comment: I don't know Spring-Kafka to answer this. The linked site is using two topics and two different deserializers. And of course if you don't have the class available on the classpath, then you get an error; that is not specific to Avro